# Why did Dr Gene punch Dr Mark?

Tags: doctor-dolittle, dr-dolittle-1998

Funny fantasy movie *[Dr Dolittle (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118998/?ref_=nv_sr_2)*

Dr Dolittle had brought the talking tiger to the hospital to
revive it. After they both saw the tiger, Dr. Mark pulled Dr. Gene aside 
and said:

> Here's what we do. We tell Johnny we're gonna fix his little  tiger up
>   after he signs. OK? Then we'll have him committed. It's perfect! That
>   way we get our money.

Then Dr. Gene punched Dr. Mark so Dr. Mark fainted.

Why did Dr. Gene punch Dr. Mark?

Comment: I assume both have a different point of view about the question, if one is allowed to use the health and live of a tiger for blackmailing someone into signing whatever...